# Using ESLint with autofix setting in vue creates endless compiling loop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, eslint, vue-cli

This is my vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')

module.exports = defineConfig({

  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
        .plugin('eslint')
        .tap(args => {
          args[0].fix = true
          return args
        })
  },
});
```

That should run eslint and fixes the issues automatically when executing npm run serve. But somehow it creates an endless compiling loop.
There are some errors which are not getting fixed by elsint e.g. 'Prop "task" should define at least its type  vue/require-prop-types'.
And I think this is the reason why it creates this endless loop.

Is there a setting that lets me keep the autofix option but it should stop after one try of fixing the eslint stuff.

Comment: I doubt it's easy to achieve. Usually lint fix is located in other points like pre-commit, and naturally occurs on save when ide is configured to do so

Comment: good hint, i will try it with husky and pre-commit. but any idea why the mentioned settings are causing endless compiling loop?